# Re-estimation of Hidden Markov Model Parameters without Knowing Hidden States

Tags: r, machine-learning, hidden-markov-model

I have been working on Hidden Markov Models (HMM) for a while. I thought that I understood the basics of HMM, however, recently I have confused about a point. Here is the issue:

Recall the 3rd problem of HMM, which is the estimation of $\lambda=[\pi,A,B]$, given observation sequence $O=[O_0,O_1,...,O_{T-1}]$. To solve this problem, we initialize the $\lambda$, either with prior knowledge (if any) or randomly, and then do the necessary calculations to update the model parameters. One of the best-known algorithms is Baum-Welch. My question is as follows:

How a HMM can update the model parameters without knowing what the hidden states really are in each iteration? Because, in any step of the algorithm, we did not tell the machine (HMM) that if it is on the right track or not.

Suppose we want to develop a rumor detector for twitter data. To be able to update the model parameters, the machine needs to know what are some examples of real rumor, right? Otherwise, how can it know?

In summary, how a HMM can update model parameters without any training?

Thank you.

Comment: Because the function you're maximizing is not a function of the hidden states. That's the short answer

Comment: Your function you're maximizing is a function of observed data though. So yes you can't train without data

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment. You say "the function you're maximizing is not a function of the hidden states", but $\pi$, $A$, and $B$ provide inference about the hidden states. Suppose, I have data about the hidden states, how to train it?

Comment: You don't have data about the hidden states. They are hidden.

Comment: OK. I have seen some papers talking about training HMM. How is that possible without having hidden state data?

Comment: Oh ok, so that's your question: why does Baum Welch work. Got it